# Conditioning twice?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I know that $P(X, Y)=P(X|Y)P(Y)$. How can we apply this to $P(X,Y|Z)$? We have already conditioned on $Z$, so can we condition it again on $Y$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use the chain rule for conditional probabilities on $P(X,Y|Z)$ to condition twice, as follows:-
$$P(X,Y|Z)=P(X|Y,Z)P(Y|Z)$$
This follows from the following - where you know that $P(X,Y)=P(X|Y)P(Y)$, so that $P(X,Y,Z)=P(X|Y,Z)P(Y,Z)$:-
$$P(X,Y|Z)=\frac{P(X,Y,Z)}{P(Z)}=\frac{P(X|Y,Z)P(Y,Z)}{P(Z)}=P(X|Y,Z)P(Y|Z)$$